# How do I write javascript files with a different extension other than .js in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

If I change the extension, Netbeans stops recognizing that it is javascript and there are underlines under all of my variable names, etc. Please help me because limitations in the php framework I am using are forcing me to label javascript files with another extension other than .js.

Using Netbeans 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <kbd>**Tools**</kbd> » <kbd>**Options**</kbd> to open Options dialog.

   [image]
2. Under <kbd>**Miscellaneous**</kbd>, activate <kbd>**Files**</kbd> tab, then
   click on the <kbd>**New**</kbd> button.

   [image]
3. Enter your new extension (w/o the dot).

   [image]
4. Select an appropriate **MIME**-type (*text/javascript* in your case) and
   click on the <kbd>**OK**</kbd> button on the bottom when you're done.

   [image]

Just curious, what framework is it that would force anyone to use JavaScript w/ other extensions than .js, please enlighten me (thanx in advance).

Comment: Thanks! It's complicated but I wanted to use CakePHP's "elements" to inject javascript into other javascript that I wrote directly into the view. CakePHP forces you to use .ctp on elements, and you can't change the extension. I realized later that I can do it a different way, but this wouldn't have completely solved my problem since I would have needed to have .ctp refer to php on some files and javascript on others, but this was informative so I'll give you the check unless someone comes along with a better answer.